# typescript - type by exec ts-code instead of generic, all in bulid-time, without codegen

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I think how to create a type that will contain all fileNames from a specific directory.

if in directory  Desktop I have files 1.js 2.ts, I should receive this type

```js
type Files = '1.js' | '2.ts';
```

Of course, I can use code generation that will create a file with this type each time I will rerun the script for this. But I want that it will be interactive, not important how it is slow. I want that when I will create a new file in this directory, vscode understands it and update the type for including a new filename, and all of it without running scripts for code generation. Just start using typescript-code-for-generate-type in build time.

I ask about a feature that is parallel to generics and permits the use ts-code & return type. Something like next secvente

```js
GenerateType<`
  const files = await fs.promises.readdir('~/Desktop');

  return \`type File = \${files.map(e => \`'\${e}'\`).join(' | '}\`;
`, { refreshIntervalMs: 200 }> // refreshInterval for optimise it, in accond with how slow is code from generator

// use it
const fileName: File = '3.js'; // should show ts error
```

Not sure that this functional exists in typescript, possible not, but it does not seem like something that is hard to add. (in comparison with other typescript features)

Comment: A compile-time type system feature that depends on runtime properties of the environment sounds highly unlikely.

Comment: Typescript doesn't have anything like a runtime type check. Typescript transpiles to javascript. All checks are done on compile time. It doesn't add new exception throwing to your code. You can also easily add this check your self.

Answer (score 1):

My research indicates that such functionality is not part of TypeScript and almost certainly never will be, according to the following GitHub Issues:

[microsoft/TypeScript#39385](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39385) "Allow `as precompiled` type cast for type inference". Declined with [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39385#issuecomment-655175659)

> Executing user code during compilation time is the first step toward madness; we don't implement features like this and don't intend to.

[microsoft/TypeScript#42212](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42212) "Bash executable types", suggested at least partly as a joke.  Closed as "out of scope" with [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42212#issuecomment-754938420)

> Tagging "Out of Scope" but let's agree that tag actually means "Too powerful for mere mortals to wield" in this case

[microsoft/TypeScript#50499](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50499) "Allow simple expressions as type ". Declined with [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50499#issuecomment-1230653357)

> We can't run arbitrary JS as part of typechecking (security nightmare), and providing a mini-JS interpreter in TS isn't a great alternative compared to adding more type system expressiveness through regular means.

So that doesn't look like it's going to happen.

---

Furthermore it seems like you're looking for some long-running background process that polls the directory, updating the types periodically.  No feature of the TypeScript *language* will ever give you that.  You might be able to use [the TypeScript Compiler API](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) or other modified build steps for your project, but that's out of scope for the question as asked (and in some sense is tantamount to code generation, which you say you don't want).